# jQuery an alternative to .keyup function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know alternative for `.keyup` function. Example

```
$(".color").keyup(function () {
    var top_header = $("#top_header").val();
    $("#top").css("background-color", top_header);
});
```

---

```
<input value="#121212" class="color" id="top_header" type="text" />
```

This code will change `id='top'` with a new background when we type to the input text.

Now I change it to [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/) to the field. So when we click to the text input will shown color generator.

Question

What should I replace `.keyup(function ()` to make make color change instantly without to have enter?

Example without using jscolor http://jsfiddle.net/5dsXT/

Comment: Color already changes intantly in the jscolor website doesnt it? http://jscolor.com/

Comment: When I look at jscolor it seems to change colour as you type just as your jsfiddle example does. Could you clarify what you are trying to do a bit more? Perhaps an example of what *isn't* working might help...

Comment: yes.. actually on div `id='top'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `onChange` event try replacing the `.keyup()` function with `.change()`.

**Example**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".color").change(function () {
        var top_header = $("#top_header").val();
        $("#top").css("background-color", top_header);
    });
});

<input value="#121212" class="color" id="top_header" type="text" />
```

**Edit** You can see an example of them using the event on their "[tweaking](http://jscolor.com/try.php#onchange)" page.

Comment: @Woho87 - Thanks. Been there a few times myself. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but if you want to bind two events to that texbox you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#top_header").bind("keyup focus", function() {
        $("#top").css("background-color", $(this).val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dsXT/2/

---

If you want to handle initial page load, focus, and keyup you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SetColor();
    $("#top_header").bind("keyup focus", SetColor);        
    function SetColor()
    {
        $("#top").css("background-color", $("#top_header").val());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dsXT/1/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is not asking how to bind two event handlers.

Comment: @Drackir actually this working and good for me to a new thing :)

Comment: @Unkown Error: Ah, the focus event must get fired when the colour is chosen. I still think onchange is more appropriate, however.